# Reorder JSON by value, showing a,b,c,a,b,c

Tags: json, sorting

I have some JSON that is in the below format. I want to have a script that rearranges this so that it's ordered by preference, but with alternating values. For instance, showing a,b,c,a,b,c. Can anyone help with this?

```
[   
    {
        "name" : "Tim",
        "preference" : "b"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Tom",
        "preference" : "b"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Steve",
        "preference" : "a"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Rick",
        "preference" : "a"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Nile",
        "preference" : "c"
    },
    {
        "name" : "James",
        "preference" : "c"
    }
]
```

Comment: What language do you script in and what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not JSON. It's just a JS object.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the people who voted to close this question as "too broad". Huh?? If you want to close it for "no effort by OP", then give that as a reason and leave a comment.

Comment: In practise i get the JSON from a mysql database using php. So there are a number of languages that could be used:
1) It could be done using a clever mysql query,
2) It could be done using php
3) It could be done using javascript - this has been covered by the post regarding underscore below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscore provides utilities suited to this task.

First, group your input by the preference field:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(input, 'preference');
```

Then convert this into an array of arrays:

```
var arrays = _.values(groups);
```

Then, "zip" the groups:

```
var result = _.zip.apply(null, arrays);
```

In one line:

```
var result = _.zip.apply(null, _.values(_.groupBy(input, 'preference')));
```

#### Non-Underscore version

If you can't/don't want to use Underscore, then you'll have to write your own versions of `groupBy` and `zip`:

```
function groupBy(array, prop) {
    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var entry = array[i];
        var val   = entry[prop];
        if (!result[val]) result[val] = [];
        result[val].push(entry);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Either this or Underscore's `_.groupBy` will transform your input into

```
{ 
    b: [ { name: 'Tim', preference: 'b' }, ... ],
    a: [ { name: 'Rick', preference: 'a' }, ... ]
}
```

To get an array of the arrays:

```
function values(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj) . sort() . map(function(key) { return obj[key]; });
}
```

This will result in

```
[ 
    [ { name: 'Tim', preference: 'b' }, ... ],
    [ { name: 'Rick', preference: 'a' }, ... ]
]
```

Then for zip:

```
function zip(arrays) {
    var result = [];
    var n      = 0;
    var more   = true;
    var array;

    while (more) {
        more = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            array = arrays[i];
            if (n < array.length) {
                more = true;
                result.push(array[n]);
            }
        }
        n++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note: this implementation of `zip` takes an array of arrays as a parameter, unlike Underscore's version, which takes the arrays as individual parameters.

Then

```
zip(values(groupBy(input, 'preference')))
```